# Different PHP version on apache and Centos 6.5 after upgrading

Tags: php, apache

I have Centos 6.5 with installed PHP 5.3.3.
I was upgraded from PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.4 successful. On commandline it show:

```
[root@localhost ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 08:05:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

But when I echo phpinfo on web it show:
PHP Version 5.3.3

I need use PHP 5.4. What should I do?

Here is result after run grep:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum list installed | grep php
php.x86_64                           5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-bcmath.x86_64                    5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-cli.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-common.x86_64                    5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-dba.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-devel.x86_64                     5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-embedded.x86_64                  5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-enchant.x86_64                   5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-fpm.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-gd.x86_64                        5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-imap.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-intl.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-ldap.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-mbstring.x86_64                  5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-mysql.x86_64                     5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-odbc.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-pdo.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-pear.noarch                      1:1.9.4-4.el6             @base
php-pecl-apc.x86_64                  3.1.9-2.el6               @base
php-pecl-apc-devel.x86_64            3.1.9-2.el6               @base
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64             3.0.5-4.el6               @base
php-pgsql.x86_64                     5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-process.x86_64                   5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-pspell.x86_64                    5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-recode.x86_64                    5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-snmp.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-soap.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-tidy.x86_64                      5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-xml.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-xmlrpc.x86_64                    5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php-zts.x86_64                       5.3.3-40.el6_6            @updates
php54.x86_64                         1.1-5.el6.centos.alt      @scl
php54-php-cli.x86_64                 5.4.16-22.el6.centos.alt  @scl
php54-php-common.x86_64              5.4.16-22.el6.centos.alt  @scl
php54-php-pear.noarch                1:1.9.4-10.el6.centos.alt @scl
php54-php-process.x86_64             5.4.16-22.el6.centos.alt  @scl
php54-php-xml.x86_64                 5.4.16-22.el6.centos.alt  @scl
php54-runtime.x86_64                 1.1-5.el6.centos.alt      @scl
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Check the Apache configure to see which PHP extension it's loading. Chances are it's not the same as your new PHP install

Comment: can you post results of this command
`yum list installed | grep php`

Comment: I've just post results of that command. Please help!

Comment: looks like you have two different versions of php installed on your system can you check config file of your apache which is in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and try to find line which looks similar to this one `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: I know a problem if you dont remove php-common before you upgrade php to 5.4. Its maybe this problem.

Comment: Now I need upgrade to PHP 5.4. What should I do?

Comment: what you need to do is to point your apache to the right module, file name is called `libphp5.so` and its somewhere in php54 folder currently apache is pointing to the 5.3 version. Version of PHP in your shell is separated from apache and that's why your cli is updated but apache not. So find php54 folder find location of file inside and update `LoadModule php5_module ...` line to new location

Comment: try this command to find the file `find / -name libphp5.so`

Comment: also after upgrade have you restarted your apache and have you checked your apache errors log?